# Python Sort files with particular filename into specific folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, operating-system, shutil

**Sample Environment**

```
    import os
    import shutil
    for filenames in os.getcwd():
       if filename.contains ('smallpig'):
            os.mkdir('Pig')
            chdir('Pig')
            os.mkdir(smallpig)
#move all the filenames which contain the name pig in it
            shutil.copy(filename-with-smallpig, Pig/smallpig)
       if if filename.contains ('dog'):
            os.mkdir('Dog')
            #move all the filenames which contain the name Dog in it
            shutil.copy(filename-with-dog, Dog)
```

How to do that in Python ?
I have already tried a little but there are many errors

Comment: This should generally work (although obviously some of this is pseudocode, not actual code).  If you're getting errors, post them.

Comment: did you use `print()` to see what you have in variables? `os.getcwd()` gives directory name, not file in folder, and it would need rather `os.listdir()`

Answer (score 0):

`os.getcwd()` returns current working directory, you can't get file names out of there. You have to use `os.listdir()` and may use a condition to choose files and avoid directories (as shown below).

Also using `os.mkdir()` in loop will throw errors because you can't create an already existing directory. So you should check if it already exists.

Try something like this

```py
import os
import shutil
cwd = os.getcwd()
files = (file for file in os.listdir(cwd) 
         if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(cwd, file)))
for filename in files:
   print(filename)
   if 'pig' in filename:
        if not os.path.exists('Pig'):
            os.mkdir('Pig')
        #move all the filenames which contain the name pig in it
        shutil.copy(filename, './Pig/'+filename)
   elif 'dog' in filename:
        if not os.path.exists('Dog'):
            os.mkdir('Dog')
        #move all the filenames which contain the name Dog in it
        shutil.copy(filename, './Dog/'+filename)
```

Comment: I have edited my question. check sample environment pig

Comment: `os.mkdir('smallpig')`  # mkdir() arguments must be a string
`shutil.copy(filename, 'Pig/smallpig') ` # arguments here must also be strings with pathname+filename
Also did you read what I typed?? you cant iterate `filenames` over a string that holds current working directory; a string will not have `.contains()` function. and to check substring [which is what I can understand from the attempt to check .contains()] 
`"abc" in big_string` is a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy files you could simply read the binary data and write in a new file:

```
import os

def copy_file(src_file,dst_folder,cat):
    cat_folder = os.path.join(dst_folder,cat)

    #check specific category folder is exitst
    if not os.path.isdir(cat_folder):
       os.mkdir(cat_folder)

    # Copying file by reading binary data and write in dst file
    with open(src_file.path,'rb') as src:
        data = src.read()
        with open(os.path.join(cat_folder,src_file.name),'wb') as dst:
            dst.write(data)
```

and your main function should be like:

```
def main():
    src_folder = os.path.join('YOUR_SOURCE_PATH')
    dst_folder = os.path.join('YOUR_DESTIONATION_PATH')

    if not os.path.isdir(dst_folder):
        os.mkdir(dst_folder)

    # Move the pointer to the destionation folder
    os.chdir(dst_folder)

    # Scan folder items and check is file
    for item in os.scandir(src_folder):
        if item.is_file():
            if 'pig' in item.name:
                copy_file(item,dst_folder,'pig')
            if 'dog' in item.name:
                copy_file(item,dst_folder,'dog')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have edited my question. check sample environment pig